# Centralizar isotope

Tags: jquery

Implementei o `isotope`. Está tudo funcionando faltando apenas alimentar o conteúdo.
O problema é que não consigo centralizar os elementos.
Já vi que se mudar para `mansory` era para centralizar, mas não funciona.
Fica assim:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Segue o código que fiz:

```js
// init Isotope
var $grid = $('.grid').isotope({
 itemSelector: '.element-item',
 layoutMode: 'fitRows'
});
// filter functions
var filterFns = {
 // show if number is greater than 50
 numberGreaterThan50: function() {
  var number = $(this).find('.number').text();
  return parseInt( number, 10 ) > 50;
 },
 // show if name ends with -ium
 ium: function() {
  var name = $(this).find('.name').text();
  return name.match( /ium$/ );
 }
};
// bind filter button click
$('.filters-button-group').on( 'click', 'button', function() {
 var filterValue = $( this ).attr('data-filter');
 // use filterFn if matches value
 filterValue = filterFns[ filterValue ] || filterValue;
 $grid.isotope({ filter: filterValue });
});
// change is-checked class on buttons
$('.button-group').each( function( i, buttonGroup ) {
 var $buttonGroup = $( buttonGroup );
 $buttonGroup.on( 'click', 'button', function() {
  $buttonGroup.find('.is-checked').removeClass('is-checked');
  $( this ).addClass('is-checked');
 });
});
```

É possível centralizar os elementos?

Comment: Rogério, este executável não serve para absolutamente nada. Recomendo a adição correta do código, com uma análise mais profunda do problema a resposta pode vir mais rápida.